# Should statically-declared character arrays with a specified size be initialized with a literal in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

For example,

gcc compiles this ok...

```
char s[7] = "abc";
```

But it gives the error "incompatible types in assignment" with...

```
char s[7];
s = "abc";
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is an initialization; it means "declare an array of 7 `char` on the stack, and fill the first 3 elements with `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and the remaining elements with `'\0'`".

In the second one, you're not initializing the array to anything.  You're then trying to assign to the array, which is never valid.  Something like this would "work":

```
const char *s;
s = "abc";
```

But the meaning would be slightly different (`s` is now a *pointer*, not an *array*).  In most situations, the difference is minimal.  But there are several important caveats, for instance you cannot modify the contents.  Also, `sizeof(s)` would given you the size of a pointer, whereas in your original code, it would have given you 7 (the size of the array).

Recommended reading is this: http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html.

Comment: Also note that in the first case, the remaining three entries are also initialised to '\0'; this can be quite useful.

Comment: I would not call the difference "minimal". Underestimating the difference between a pointer and an array is one of the most common and dangerous mistakes C newbies make.

Comment: @R..: Yes and no.  I agree that it's a fundamental point to understand.  But it's very rare that I actually write code where the difference matters.